# Android Volley Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-volley

I'm attempting to convert a previously Activity-based tutorial to a Fragment, but I continue to run into the NullPointerException error on my Adapter.

The tutorial is based on [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) and I have slimmed down the constructor for the Adapter because it used to be calling an Activity.

There is one possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464474/how-to-call-a-constructor-of-a-class-with-activity-as-argument-inside-a-fragment) but nobody knows how to proceed with the same possible question.

I want to convert everything to a working Fragment.  Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Main converted class:

```
public class mainViewController2 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = mainViewController2.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainviewcontroller2_fragment, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();


        //where the error shows up?
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

        return v;
    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

FeedListAdapter:

```
 public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

    Context context;

    ImageLoader imageLoader;

     public FeedListAdapter(Context ctx,List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.context= ctx;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
            TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
            NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

            FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

            name.setText(item.getName());

            // Converting timestamp into x ago format
            CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                    Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
            timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

            // Chcek for empty status message
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
                statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
                statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // status is empty, remove from view
                statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // Checking for null feed url
            if (item.getUrl() != null) {
                url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                        + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

                // Making url clickable
                url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // url is null, remove from the view
                url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // user profile pic
            profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

            // Feed image
            if (item.getImge() != null) {
                feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
                feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                feedImageView
                        .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

LogCat errors:

```
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279): Process: com.rynovation.kline, PID: 8279
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at androidFeedClasses.FeedListAdapter.<init>(FeedListAdapter.java:35)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController2.onCreateView(mainViewController2.java:51)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-06 02:51:55.823: E/AndroidRuntime(8279):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your adapter is all over the place. Read about the ViewHolder pattern and try to create something similar. Here's the google version but try searching for examples as well: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 27):

I guess you missed a simple code in your manifest file. Your `AppController` package extends `Application` , So the application tag in your manifest is searching for the `AppController` but isn't able to find.

Just Write this simple code in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`android:name = your.package.AppController`

Comment: sir, you are time saver.

Answer (score 11):

A little late maybe, but a representative answer to user3902144's answer:

Similar Answer to this question : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897486/nullpointerexception-when-using-customlistadapter/25903725#25903725)

You may have missed out this from your manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name="<package-name>.app.AppController" // <-- this one
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

That's why onCreate never called and mInstance is null.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! Never too late haha

Comment: too late answer helped me :-)

Comment: If you can't because have multidex ?

Comment: @delive can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, it seems like you're calling `getActivity()` inside `onCreateView()`. You should be getting the activity in `onActivityCreated` instead where it shouldn't be null.

Comment: What do you suggest I do?  It's meant to be a Fragment, not an Activity. Can you please write an example if possible?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to reach into the activity to find the list view? Is the listview not inside R.layout.mainviewcontroller2_fragment?

Comment: Where's the constructor for FeedListAdapter that only takes in one argument: `new FeedListAdapter(feedItems);`? I'm only seeing `public FeedListAdapter(Context ctx,List<FeedItem> feedItems)`

Comment: It apparently doesn't exist.  Any ideas of what it should look like?

Comment: Can you click on it to go to the method declaration? It should exist somewhere. Otherwise, your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: It goes to the same FeedListAdapter, there isn't a specific one that allows for one argument in the constructor.

Comment: What's line 35 inside FeedListAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

Change this from

```
listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

This is because `getActivity()` is generally used for as a `Context`  in Fragment. While you'r find id for your `UI` elements in Fragment then you have to give reference of your `View's` object which will be returned in `onCreateView()` method.

Update:

Change your Adapter Like,

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(),feedItems);
```

Now in its Constructor

```
 ImageLoader imageLoader;

 public FeedListAdapter(Context ctx,List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.context= ctx;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader()
 }
```

Now in your adapter class use `context` variable as a `Context`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error.  I think this may be caused in the FeedListAdapter?

Comment: Ok, I updated my post as well to reflect your changes.  However, the problem now seems to be in the constructor.  See updated logcat above please.

Comment: add this line inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) to your adapter constructor

Comment: Ok, well I did that and now I'm getting an error pointing there via the new logcat/updated code.  See above.

Comment: Any ideas left?  I did exactly what you said and still the same error is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all your params carefully, make sure not to send any null value in params, if using some stored values then use the condition like below:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
 if(paramValue!= null)
     params.put("paramKey", paramValue);
  else
     params.put("paramKey", "anyOtherDefaultValue");
 return params;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

//I was Stack in This Error and I solved this just by Writing this in your AppController Class.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```